# Django webpage display login when it should be logout

Tags: html, django

I have used Django 1.11.14， python 2.7 and win 7 to build a website which could let registered user to login.
however, when I log in, some page display login link again when it should be logout link.

main page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  {% block title %}<title>xxxxx</title>{% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  {% block sidebar %}
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <br>
    <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}"><mark>Home</mark></a></li>
      <br>
    <li><a href="{% url 'FWs' %}"><mark>FW request</mark></a></li>
      <br>

  </ul>
 
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <li>User: {{ user.get_username }}</li>
     <li><a href="{% url 'my-applied' %}"><mark>My applied</mark></a></li>
      <br>
     <li><a href="{% url 'logout'%}?next={{request.path}}"><mark>Logout</mark></a></li>
   {% else %}
     <li><a href="{% url 'login'%}?next={{request.path}}"><mark>Login</mark></a></li>
   {% endif %} 
  </ul>
  
   {% if user.is_staff %}
   <hr />
   <ul class="sidebar-nav">
   <li>Staff</li>
   {% if perms.catalog.can_mark_returned %}
   <li><a href="{% url 'all-applied' %}"><mark>All applied</mark></a></li>
   {% endif %}
   </ul>
    {% endif %}
 
{% endblock %}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 ">
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  
  {% block pagination %}
    {% if is_paginated %}
        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="page-current">
                    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endblock %} 
  
  
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

FW_request

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p style = "color:#FF0000";> XXx</p>


    {% if FW_list %}
    <ul>
      {% for FWinst in FW_list %}
        {% if FWinst.is_approved %}
        <p style = "color:#008000";>xxxx</p>
        <p></p>
        <br>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {% else %}
      <p>Nothing.</p>
    {% endif %}       
{% endblock %}
```

view.py

```
class LoanedFWsByUserListView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.ListView, FormView):


model = XX
paginate_by = 10
template_name = 'FW_request.html'
def get(self, request):
    form = xx[![enter image description here][1]][1]Form()
    FW_list = FW.objects.all().order_by('approve_time').reverse()        
    return render_to_response(self.template_name, locals())
```

when I login to the mainpage, it is correct, but when I click other tab like My applied, although I am still in the status of login, it shows login on the page, where it should be logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `render_to_response` you should use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function. This make request available in template.

```
def get(self, request):
    form = xx[![enter image description here][1]][1]Form()
    FW_list = FW.objects.all().order_by('approve_time').reverse()        
    return render(self.request, self.template_name, locals())
```

Comment: I have changed return render_to_response(self.template_name, locals()) to return render(self.template_name, locals())  but  error called TemplateDoesNotExist occured

Comment: @py2exe I've added code to answer. First argument of render should be request: `return render(self.request, self.template_name, locals())`.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the point of using class based views here. You should rarely, if ever, be defining `get` (or `post`). In this case you should only define `get_context_data` to add your FW_list, and let the view handle creating the form and rendering the template.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['FW_list'] = FW.objects.all().order_by('approve_time').reverse()        
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```